# Getting Undefined offset 0 in PHP While not attachment using in Email

Tags: php, yii

Here am using this code for email sending, its working perfectly while adding attachments, but while sending mail without attachments, am getting error as

> Undefined offset 0

Mycode

```
if($model->attachment) 
                {
                    $message = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                    ->setFrom([ Yii::$app->user->identity->email => 'Fiducial Insurance'])
                    ->setTo($model->email)
                    ->setSubject($model->subject)
                    ->setHtmlBody($model->content);

                    foreach ($model->attachment as $file) 
                    {
                        $file->saveAs('emailattachments/' .$file->baseName. '.' . $file->extension);
                        $filename = 'emailattachments/' .$file->baseName. '.' . $file->extension;
                        $message->attach($filename);
                    }

                    $columns = array_map(function($column) {
                        return 'emailattachments/' . $column;
                    }, $model->attachment);
                    $model->attachment = implode(', ', $columns);

                    $message->send();

                }
                else
                {
                    $message = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                    ->setFrom([ Yii::$app->user->identity->email => 'Fiducial Insurance'])
                    ->setTo($model->email)
                    ->setSubject($model->subject)
                    ->setHtmlBody($model->content)
                    ->send();
                }
                $model->save();
```

How to sort out this error

Comment: What line gives the error? Please provide the complete error you are receiving.

Comment: PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException

Undefined offset: 0 , C:\wamp\www\fiducial\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the lines that add the attachment in an `if` that only gets executed if there is at least one attachment.

```
                //...
                $hasAttachment = false;
                foreach ($model->attachment as $file) 
                {
                    $hasAttachment = true;
                    $file->saveAs('emailattachments/' .$file->baseName. '.' . $file->extension);
                    $filename = 'emailattachments/' .$file->baseName. '.' . $file->extension;
                    $message->attach($filename);
                }

                if($hasAttachment) {
                    $columns = array_map(function($column) {
                        return 'emailattachments/' . $column;
                    }, $model->attachment);
                    $model->attachment = implode(', ', $columns);
                }
                //...
```

Please try if count($model->attachment) would work too. The above approach is more like a workaround.

Why does this happen?

```
$model->attachment == array() == true
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

This means you get inside that block of code even if the array is empty. You wouldn't get into the block of code if the variable was undefined, which you can simulate using `unset($model->attachment)`

Comment: if i use unset($model->attachment) attachment is not working